# Why liquibase.bat script cannot find jvm.cfg?

Tags: java, liquibase

I cant run liquibase script to DB with the error "could not open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'"
Actualy, ./amd64/ doesnt exist on my drive

```
C:\dev\projects\hrportal\persistence\src\main\resources\scripts>..\liquibase\liquibase-3.8.4\liquibase.bat       --driver=org.postgresql.Driver       --classpath=..       --url="jdbc:postgresql://localh
ost:5432/hrportal"       --changeLogFile=db/liquibase_pg/changelog-master.xml       --username=postgres       --password=1234567890     update
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

Why do script assign to this path? Where it is defined?
JDK is install in the other path, so I have no idea why script search smthg in "Program Files (x86)..." directory

liquibase.bat script is:

```
@echo off
if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem %~dp0 is expanded pathname of the current script under NT
set LIQUIBASE_HOME="%~dp0"

set CP=.
for /R %LIQUIBASE_HOME% %%f in (liquibase*.jar) do set CP=!CP!;%%f
for /R %LIQUIBASE_HOME%\lib %%f in (*.jar) do set CP=!CP!;%%f
rem remove quotes around LIQUIBASE_HOME
set LIQUIBASE_HOME=%LIQUIBASE_HOME:"=%
rem add the lib directory itself to the classpath
set CP=!CP!;!LIQUIBASE_HOME!lib

rem special characters may be lost
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_OPTS set JAVA_OPTS=-Dprefer.internal.xsd=true

java -cp "%CP%" %JAVA_OPTS% liquibase.integration.commandline.Main %*
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically Liquibase runs on Java. I would suggest you to update your java, and make sure it is the path > `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\...`
You can find more information on this page [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/installation/liquibase-system-requirements.html)

[image]